# Batch script crashing at if statement

Tags: batch-file

I have been troubleshooting this for hours now with no success. I have googled and read through numerous forums as well to no avail. I have a batch script I was writing for my boss to use for our company. The goal seemed simple enough and didn't really require any sort of overly complex techniques. I just wanted to make a script we could run to add an exe or script to task scheduler. That part I actually have down. It's in the text and options before that i'm having issues. From what I can tell I don't have syntax errors, yet the script still crashes on an if statement.

```
@echo off

net session 1>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto begin
if %errorlevel% GTR 0 goto eof

:begin
set CREATE_OR_DELETE=CREATE
set TASKNAME=TASK
set SCHEDULE=ONSTART
set TASKRUN=cmd.exe

if "%*"=="" (
goto getinfo
) else (
goto parsetags
)

:getinfo
choice /c CD /n /m "Are you (c)reating or (d)eleting?"
if errorlevel 1 set CREATE_OR_DELETE=CREATE
if errorlevel 2 set CREATE_OR_DELETE=DELETE
cls

set /p TASKNAME="What is the name of the task you're creating/deleting :: "
cls

if not %CREATE_OR_DELETE%==DELETE (
::the code crashes on the above if statement
::that is why I'm dumbfounded
)

:eof
```

I'll leave off the rest of the code since it's not relevant to the problem. At the last if statement in the code the script just exits without any message or error. I haven't been able to get the script to get past that if statement at all. I've tried just about every variation I can think of. Quotes, Capitalization, spaces, empty new lines, literally anything I looked up or thought of. Nothing has worked. Please don't bash me too hard as batch is fairly new to me, I typically use other languages.

--------------------EDIT--------------------

I apologize for the length / complexity of this code. I only included the before lines of code because the script is crashing on a line that doesn't have syntax errors, which leads me to believe there might be some intricacy in the lines before that isn't necessarily wrong but that I am not aware of. Also please keep in mind I will only be applying changes when i'm actually at the machine with the code on it.

Comment: Can we make the problem any simpler to find out what's causing it Devon?

Comment: This code is not valid: `set /p TASKNAME /n /m`.

Comment: Lose the spaces around the `=` in the first if statement. When testing errorlevel test from high to low. See `if /?`

Comment: `if ErrorLevel 1` means *if ErrorLevel is **greater than or equal to** 1*, so it's true for both choices; hence put `if ErrorLevel 2` first...

Comment: @aschipfl In this particular instance, the code does not need to be in HIGH to LOW.  If the person answers D, the errorlevel gets set to 2 and assigns `DELETE` to the variable. Yes it triggers both IF commands to be true but it still sets the variable correctly.

Comment: @Devon Mathews, removing the `/n /m` from the line of code I pointed out still does not make the line of code valid.  You should be able to see when you run your code that it is crashing on that line.  You say you program in other languages but apparently you are failing to read the help file for the `SET` command.  The syntax for using `SET /P` is clearly defined in the help: `SET /P variable=[promptString]`.  If you know anything about command syntax, code inside brackets are optional. Everything else is not optional. You need an equals symbol. You can't do an assignement without one.

Comment: @squashman the original code isn't wrong, that is a fat finger instance as I quickly jotted this down at the end of my work shift. Let's focus on the real issue of why that one if statement is crashing the code.

Comment: Also thank you all for commenting, there has been some useful information regarding syntax such as the errorlevel oversight. Usually when I post code to this website there are some errors that just happened as a result of me hand typing it over. Just quick reminders help me iron those out pretty fast.

Comment: Any code question you provide should be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider reading, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You don't have any valid code inside the code block of the IF command. You can't have just a single line that starts with a double colon inside a parentheses code block. That is why the `IF` command fails. If you have actual code that is inside the parentheses then please post it.

Comment: There are a ton of lines of code inside the if statement. It never makes it to them. The script crashes on that if statement. I've said this before, that's why I asked the question in the first place. Please don't sit and bash me. If you don't have any input on it, just leave it at that. I've tested to confirm that the if statement is where it crashes by placing an echo 1234 & pause before the if statement. The code echoes correctly, then crashes. When I move the echo after the statement or inside the statement, it never makes it to it, it crashes before.

Comment: The `if` to the closing `)` is parsed at once. So your error may not be caused by the `if not %CREATE_OR_DELETE%==DELETE (` but rather any invalid syntax between the `(` and the closing `)`. Suggest you use `if %CREATE_OR_DELETE%==DELETE goto :create`, which allows the code after the `goto` and before the label to be not enclosed between `(` and a closing `)`. This may allow you to view the line generating the error and avoids use of delayed expansion which is not enabled and is possibly why it is crashing.

Comment: Thank you. That helps explain a lot about what the issue might be. Tomorrow when I get to work I will use that to maybe troubleshoot some. If that's the issue I would ask you to maybe submit that as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: First rules of debugging a batch file. 1) At the top of you script change `@ECHO OFF` to `@ECHO ON`.  2) Open up a cmd prompt and execute the batch file. This way you will see what the error is. Now after Michaels comment do yo understand why you need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If I had a dollar for every time someone said they didn't provide anymore of their code because they didn't think it was important but it was, I wouldn't have to play the lottery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo on
@setlocal
@set "prompt=--$G "

set "CREATE_OR_DELETE=CREATE"
for %%A in (:test1 :test2) do call %%A
goto :eof


:test1
rem *** Test 1 ***

if %CREATE_OR_DELETE%==DELETE goto :label
set "var=1"
if %var%==%CREATE_OR_DELETE% echo OK
set "var="
:label
goto :eof


:test2
rem *** Test 2 ***

if %CREATE_OR_DELETE%==DELETE (
    set "var=1"
    if %var%==%CREATE_OR_DELETE% echo OK
    set "var="
)
goto :eof
```

This example may show your recognized problem.

The label `:test1` uses the `goto :label` idea to avoid the code
between `(` and `)` which is parsed at once. This has the advantage
of each command being parsed separately, so you can detect an error
more easily. It can also avoid variable expansion issues where delayed
expansion may need to be enabled.

The label `:test2` is using code between `(` and `)`. This causes
a error on parsing as `%var%` is undefined due to delayed expansion
not being enabled. The error description may be meanless in variation
of what code used.

To sum up, having lots of commands between `(` and `)` can be efficient,
though can differcult to debug.

---

Here is your code with some changes which may help.

```
@echo off

net session 1>nul 2>nul || goto :eof

:begin
set "CREATE_OR_DELETE=CREATE"
set "TASKNAME=TASK"
set "SCHEDULE=ONSTART"
set "TASKRUN=cmd.exe"
set ALLARGS=%*

if not defined ALLARGS (
    goto getinfo
) else (
    goto parsetags
)

:getinfo
choice /c CD /n /m "Are you (c)reating or (d)eleting?"
:: "obsolete as already set" if errorlevel 1 set CREATE_OR_DELETE=CREATE
if errorlevel 2 set "CREATE_OR_DELETE=DELETE"
cls

set /p "TASKNAME=What is the name of the task you're creating/deleting :: "
cls

if "%CREATE_OR_DELETE%" == "DELETE" goto :skip_create
::the code crashes on the above if statement
::that is why I'm dumbfounded

:skip_create
```

- Double quoted many set commands.
- `ALLARGS` tested if defined rather then handling `%*` directly which can be risky.
- Removed label `:eof` as it does not need to be inserted.
  `goto` knows it represents End Of File.
- `errorlevel 1` check after `choice` is commented as you have it already assigned.
- `goto :skip_create` added to avoid enclosing the create code between `(` and `)`.